# Elastic Beanstalk docker error

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting a cryptic error when trying to update the configuration of a single-container Docker application.  Anybody have an idea of what might cause this, or how to go about debugging it?

```
ERROR [3009]  : Command execution failed:
   [CMD-ConfigDeploy/ConfigDeployStage0/ConfigDeployPreHook/00run.sh] 
   command failed with error code 1:
   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/pre/00run.sh
   docker: "tag" requires 2 arguments. See 'docker tag --help'.
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ActivityFatalError)
```

Answer (score 8):

I've seen this one before, and believe this happens when the Docker container failed to build. The command that failed is the one which runs your container, and it's failing (IIRC) because it can't find the container from the previous build step. Things to try:

- Does the Docker container build successfully with `eb local`? (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/run-docker-apps-locally-using-the-elastic-beanstalk-eb-cli/)
- Try checking `eb-activity.log` for errors during the build process
- Terminate the EC2 instance or rebuild the EB environment (sometimes smaller instances get out-of-memory errors that prevent further deployments)

Answer (score 6):

It could happen if your application fails to start successfully the first time it deploys. Just started having this problem myself.

Take a look at /var/log/eb-activity.log on your server... you may see something like:

> [2015-07-23T00:19:11.015Z] INFO  [2624]  - [CMD-Startup/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/00run.sh] : Starting activity...
>
> [2015-07-23T00:19:17.506Z] INFO  [2624]  - [CMD-Startup/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/00run.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
>     aca80d7accfe4800ff04992e2f89a1e05689423d286deee31b53bf470ce89afb
>     Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: bleBeanFactory.java:942)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
>           ... 93 more. Check snapshot logs for details. (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
>   caused by: jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
>     aca80d7accfe4800ff04992e2f89a1e05689423d286deee31b53bf470ce89afb
>     Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: bleBeanFactory.java:942)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
>           ... 93 more. Check snapshot logs for details. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
>
> [2015-07-23T00:19:17.506Z] INFO  [2624]  - [CMD-Startup/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/00run.sh] : Activity failed.
>
> [2015-07-23T00:19:17.507Z] INFO  [2624]  - [CMD-Startup/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Activity failed.
>
> [2015-07-23T00:19:17.507Z] INFO  [2624]  - [CMD-Startup/StartupStage1] : Activity failed.
>
> [2015-07-23T00:19:17.507Z] INFO  [2624]  - [CMD-Startup] : Completed activity. Result:
>     Command CMD-Startup(stage 1) failed.

Next, look at /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app If you see an unexpected-quit.log then it should contain the errors that your application logged as it tried, unsuccessfully, to start.

Unfortunately, in my case, it's failing to start because an environment variable is missing. However, AWS prevents me from updating the configuration while the beanstalk is in this state. And I can't specify the environment variables while I create the environment. So I'm not sure what I'll do to fix the problem.

Comment: Simple edit your auto scaling group associated to your environment and set a desired number of instances to 0 (same for Min). Wait until your instance is destroyed. When you Beanstalk environment has no instance, update your environment variables. Wait for the update to finish. Change your auto scaling group back. TADAAAAA, you solved your problem :)

Comment: I have the exact same issue as Shannon's. @kiddouk your solution is not working for me, EB complained that the value must be >= 1.

Comment: The answer for me was in the unexpected-quit.log, thank you!

Comment: Looking in the right log file is what got me to my solution to a similar problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have the exact same issue as @Shannon's. My workaround is

- first, deploy a sample Dockerfile that guarantees to work,
- then setup all environment variables my real Docker app would need,
- finally redeploy the real Docker app.

A sample Dockerfile copy-pasted from [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker-singlecontainer-deploy.html):

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx zip curl

RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN curl -o /usr/share/nginx/www/master.zip -L https://codeload.github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048/zip/master
RUN cd /usr/share/nginx/www/ && unzip master.zip && mv 2048-master/* . && rm -rf 2048-master master.zip

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-c", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"]
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way to do I think... no scripts, just a bit of a hack to get the project off the ground and set the env variables. +1

Comment: Disappointing AWS requires a hack like this for what I imagine is a common scenario. You should be able to set env vars when setting up the environment in the web UI. Thanks for the helpful solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide your environment variables on the command line in the **eb create** and **eb clone** commands. These are set *before* the create or clone task so the environment will come up with them set.

See the eb cli help. For example...

`$ eb create -h
...
--envvars ENVVARS     a comma-separated list of environment variables as
                       key=value pairs
...`